# ~んです should be used in what condition?

Tags: grammar

> 1. どこでかいますか。
> 2. どこでかったんですか。

The meaning of the two sentences are same, right? Yet, in what condition I need to use～んですか。

Comment: it seems to me that this is not a duplicate. the first sentence says either "where will you buy it?" or "where do i buy it?". the second sentence doesn't seem to make any sense. but the verb is in the past tense so it would be rendered as "it's that where did i buy it?". but as a nonnative speaker maybe I'm missing something. nevertheless i think the question should be opened for someone to answer why these two sentences don't say the same thing and what if anything the second sentence says.

Comment: @A.Ellett The first is as you say "Where can it be bought?" / "Where can you buy it?" etc. The second makes perfect sense but is slightly more colloquial. As you guessed it means "Where did you buy it?". 買った+ ん is a slightly more colloquial way of saying 買った.

Comment: @TheWanderingCoder Thank you.  I wanted to translate the first with "can", but since it didn't say かえます, I wasn't sure.  Sometimes I'm not sure whether "can" in English is just our sloppy way of speaking or not.

Comment: @A.Ellett Can would likely use some form of 変**え**ます